# Elasticsearch Integration Tests Framework

Tags: java, scala, unit-testing, elasticsearch, specs2

I am using Elasticsearch 2.3, and I would like to spin up for Integration Tests an In-Memory node that can be accessed via HTTP.

I have some to

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/integration-tests.html

Can I use this framework with Specs2?

I use Scala, therefore it would be nice to have it working in my Stack with Specs2, and not only JUnit.

Again, I want to test my data accessing it over the Rest API of Elastic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to start an in memory elastic search

```
import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.ImmutableSettings._
import org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder._

class InMemoryEmbeddedElasticSearch {

    def doStart(): Unit = node.start

    def stop(): Unit = {
        node.stop()
        node.close()
    }

    private val dataDirectory = s"target/elastic/"

    private val node = 
        nodeBuilder().settings(
            settingsBuilder.put("node.local", "false",
                                "network.host", "127.0.0.1",
                                "http.enabled", "true",
                                "path.data", dataDirectory))
                     .node()
}
```